# QFileSystemWatcher::files() doesn't return a list of files

Tags: c++, qt, qfilesystemwatcher

I'm using `QFileSystemWatcher` for watching for changes in a directory that I set in `watcher->addPath("myPath")` method.

When I call `watcher->directories()` I see `myPath`.

But when I call `watcher->files()` I see nothing. I thought I will see files in directory when I use this method.

What should I do to see files in a directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QFileSystemWatcher` is intended to watch changes in the file system.

To obtain a list of files in a directory use [QDir::entryList](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html).

Example:

```
QString files = QDir("c:\\").entryList(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
```

If you need to watch changes in a directory (file added/renamed or removed events) you use `addPath` with a directory and listen to `directoryChanged` signal.
If you need to watch a file content change you use `addPath` with a full path to a file and listen to `fileChanged` signal.

Accordingly `directories` returns a list of directories you have added and `files` returns a list of files you have added.

Comment: I listen signal that you show, but my slot doesn't responds because of empty list of files - so this signal doesn't emit when I add some files to directory:(

Comment: There is nothing in common between `directoryChanged` and method `files`. Use `QDir` to obtain a list of files.